# Trouble adding elements to array

Tags: export, list-manipulation

I need to generate array and export it to file.

For n = 1 , second element must be 0
For n = 2.. 819, second element must be 1
For n = 820.. 1637, second element must be -1
For n = 1638.. 16384, second element again must be 0.

At first I tried just generating for n up to 10:

```
n1 = Reap[For[i = 1, i < 2, i++, Sow[i]; Sow[0]];
 ][[2, 1]]~Partition~2; 
array1 = n1;
n10 = Reap[For[i = 2, i < 10, i++, Sow[i]; Sow[1]];
 ][[2, 1]]~Partition~2;
AppendTo[array1, n10];
Export["C:\\Users\\Justas\\Desktop\\array1.txt", array1, "Table"];
FilePrint["C:\\Users\\Justas\\Desktop\\array1.txt"]
```

But result was not what I expected:

```
1   0
{2, 1}  {3, 1}  {4, 1}  {5, 1}  {6, 1}  {7, 1}  {8, 1}  {9, 1}
```

I need to have all elements of array printed to file like the first one:

```
n1  value1
n2  value2
```

.. and so on.

Does anyone has any ideas how to do it?
Also I'm curious if I can change this default gap with simple space?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Join[{#, 0} & /@ Range[1], {#, 1} & /@ Range[2, 819], {#, -1} & /@ 
  Range[820, 1637], {#, 0} & /@ Range[1638, 16384]]`

Comment: Try looking up `ConstantArray`, `Array` and `Table`. Function definitions with multiple rules, such as `f[n_/;2<=n<=10]=1;f[n_/;11<=n<=100]=-1;` will be helpful to use with `Array` or with `Table`, such as `Table[{n, f[n]}, {n, 100}]`

Comment: Will look into it @LLlAMnYP Thanks for directions.

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: There are [things to do after your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Its a good idea to stay vigilant some time after you get the first answer, better approaches may come later improving over a previous reply and experienced users may point to caveats. Therefore, new users may **wait 24 hours** before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the deserving answers and a bit more before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one. (Links contain useful information)

Comment: @rhermans I understand why waiting before accepting. But I'm not sure about waiting before _voting_

Comment: @rhermans Well, I usually upvote _after_ testing an answer, but surely not _one day_ after testing it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
 array = Join[
   {{1, 0}},
   Table[
     {n, 1},
     {n, 2, 819}
   ],
   Table[
     {n, -1},
     {n, 820, 1637}
   ],
   Table[
     {n, 0},
     {n, 1638, 16384}
   ]
 ];
```

To print:

```
Grid[array]
```

Or with a space instead:

```
TableForm[array,TableSpacing->{1,1}]
```

To export with a space:

```
Export[
  "$FILENAME", 
  Grid[array],
  "Table", 
  "FieldSeparators" -> " "
]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Export["file.txt", Array[{#, Piecewise[
     {
      {0, # == 1}
      , {1, 2 <= # <= 819}
      , {-1, 820 <= # <= 1637}
      }, 0]
    } &, 16384], "Table"]
```